# Accessing values from Alfresco's alfresco-global.properties file by javascript controller of a web script?

Tags: javascript, alfresco

I found out its possible to access the global properties of an alfresco instance by exposing the following property in a bean definition.

```
<property name="properties">
    <ref bean="global-properties"/>
</property>
```

But I want to access the global properties by the javascript controller of a webscript. How is this possible?

running alfresco 3.4.d

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is a root object for global properties,

but any information available in a Spring bean can be available to a javascript controller using ProcessorExtension an ScriptProcessorRegistry mecanism of the Surf Framework.

using them you can define and add your own root object with the properties (method) you'd like to have.

Comment: there is a global-properties bean defined in 'core-services-context.xml'

Comment: I was saying I'm not sure there is a root object in javascript for global properties.

Comment: alfresco forum is saying that you define a bean with the parent 'baseJavaScriptExtension" and a property 'extensionName' which will register the bean as a root object for all webscripts.

Comment: No, you are right of course, there is no root object available for global properties. This is why i want to create it! But I cant get it working. 
if i define a bean with parent of 'baseJavaScriptExtension' i receive org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException

Comment: This error is because you haven't added the setter for your bean property in the Java class, if you are not familiar with the Spring framework and dependency injection you should have a look at the documentation then. I know that script processor extension and registration is not well documented by Alfresco :(

Comment: In the forums it is told that it should be an instance of java.util.Properties. I dont want to edit this class!